# Why is my <a href="test.xls"> is working and .txt is not?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a folder named **Test**. I have some .xls files and .txt , .doc files in it.

In the html I have

```
<p> <a href="../../Test/Stats.xls">Download excel file </a> </p> 
- when I click on this link it is opening a download window (Working fine) 

<p> <a href="../../Test/Stats.txt">Download Text file </a> </p> 

<p> <a href="../../Test/Stats.doc">Download excel file </a> </p>
```

But these 2 are not working. Instead of opening a download window they are going to that .doc file link and saying that the page cannot be found.

why the download window is coming for .xls and not for .do or .doc? How can I fix this??

Comment: Page not found ? Filenames Stats.doc and Stats.txt really exists within the folder ?

Comment: You may need to adjust your server's MIME types.

Comment: The default behavior of the browser for a Text file (.txt) is to open the page as if it were a webpage and not prompt to download. That wouldn't explain why would get a 404 error. If you're using IIS 7 it is possible that you don't have the mime types for .DOC/.DOCX and .TXT as allowed extensions. There could be permission issues preventing the IIS_USER account access. Have you used a utility like Fiddler to watch the request to IIS and see the HTTP status code? Have you checked your IIS logs?

Comment: Hi Splash - I added the MIME Type on IIS for .doc and still I am getting the error when I click on .doc hyperlink.

Comment: When I checked the event log I am seeing a warning with event Id 1309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your server's MIME types, otherwise either the file will not be served up (and you'll get a 404) or the browser will not know how to handle the type of file.

See [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Properly_Configuring_Server_MIME_Types#How_to_set_up_your_server_to_send_the_correct_MIME_types) for more information.

Comment: Are you sure the path you are pointing to exists and is within the web site's virtual directory? Check the details of the Event ID 1309...I'll bet you'll see something like "The system cannot find the path specified".

Answer (score 1):

Sounds silly, but I'm guessing that you need to check the file names and references to them and make sure they are exactly the same. Unless you are on a Windows box, case sensitivity is something to take into account too.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to check this http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET